# node.js join - coming from php implode

Tags: node.js, join, implode

I have the following code in PHP:

```
$IDs = implode(",", array_keys($result["matches"]));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($IDs)";
```

I am "translating" it into Node.js, and I suppose that implode becomes array.join, so I tried this:

```
var ids = Object.keys(answer['matches']).join(",");
var sql = "SELECT * FROM xml_it WHERE id IN (" + ids + ")";
```

now, if I echo the PHP $sql variable, I get the expected result:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (3187,3220,3233,3245,3246,3251,3253,3256, ...
```

BUT, with node.js, I am getting this:

```
SELECT * FROM xml_it WHERE id_xml IN ([0,1,2,3,4, ...
```

The answer['matches'] obviously is the same result (it's basically a Sphinx search result)

Any idea why I am not getting it as a string but as object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `Object.keys(obj)` to mirror what `array_keys` does.

Right now you're grabbing the whole object, not just the keys.

Comment: oh, right! totally missed that! it's working now! it's so easy to miss such small things!

Comment: just give me 10 minutes to be able to mark yours as the right answer

Comment: uhm, I still seem to have a problem. with the fixed code you game me, I get on php the right ids (like 2356, 4658, etc.) but, on node, I am getting 0,1,2,3,... etc. What might it be? I suppose it's because I am using Object.keys, and it should be Object.values . But it doesn't work, it gives TypeError: Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'values'

Comment: if you output `answer['matches']` to console, what does the structure look like?

Comment: `[{"doc":1,"weight":1,"attrs":{}},{"doc":2,"weight":1,"attrs":{}},{"doc":6,"weight":1,"attrs":{}},...`

Comment: it seems like your data is stored differently then.. `Object.keys` is returning the indexes of the array.. the data for `2356`,`4658` ids has to be somewhere, the problem probably is how that 'matches' array is getting created, and the result compared to how php does it.

Comment: Words can't describe how much I hate Sphinx... I am also getting slightly different ids between the two clients...

Comment: is there no way to get this "doc" attribute?

Comment: to get an array of the doc ids you'd do a `map()`...  `var outarray = inarray.map( function( o ) { return o.doc; } );`